How to sum delimited text in python in excel
I slowly started using python in excel. Somehow I managing the code, however this time I I have received my output data is delimited with ",". How to do it with py option excel.
Based on the below pic, sum of aa,dd,ee is 18, bb,gg is 9 and so on.. I can do it sum individual but not sure how to deal with delimited text. Any help would appreciate. Thank you.


Could you please clarify what you want to do? Do you want a Python or Excel solution?

@Parmesh In Excel Office 365, Python option is also available. I would like to get the result through python code in excel.

What result would you like to get, to add numbers in g,or numbers in j,or what??

@redoc I just want the sum in g column.  ex: From input table aa = 3, dd = 4, ee = 9. & Output data is delimited aa,dd,ee. so the sum is 16.

okay,your image was misleading,maybe remove those values in g, so people understand that those have to be found.

So F is not the output, but is to be used to get G, right? Do you need it to be a =PY() solution, or would a regular Excel formula do as well?

Enter in E2 with =PY:
df_nv = xl("A1:B10", headers=True)
names = xl("D2:D5").iloc[:,0]
nv = dict(zip(df_nv["Name"],df_nv["Value"]))

def sum_split(a):
    return sum(map(lambda a: nv[a], a.split(",")))

list(map(sum_split, names))



Siddharth Rout's answer has better checks - for example xl returns dataFrame only for multi-cell inputs.

Beautiful! Good use of map() within sum() I am still learning Python so this was a good lesson!

Thank you @SiddharthRout, I'm also learning it. BTW, checking for dataFrame with xl is good. I'll mention that in my answer.

I am trying to self learn so I am all ears for suggestions... Any good books or online sites that you would recommend?

@SiddharthRout, I use mainly https://docs.python.org/3/index.html, but like "Fluent Python" also.

Thanky Thanky :)


I would like to get the result through python code in excel. –
Srikanth
Commented9 hours ago

You do not need python for this but if you are keen on learning how to do this in Python, then see this. I have commented the code but if you still want an explanation for a specific line, simply ask :)
Let's say your data looks like this.

Is this what you are trying? Put this code in G3 in Python Mode and press CTL + ENTER.
import pandas as pd

#~~> Load data from I2:J11 into a dataframe
data_df = xl("I2:J11", headers=True)

#~~> Get the delimited list from F3:F6
delimited_lists = xl("F3:F6")[0].tolist() if isinstance(xl("F3:F6"), pd.DataFrame) else xl("F3:F6")

#~~> Create dictionary of Header1 and Header2
key_value_dict = dict(zip(data_df.iloc[:, 0], data_df.iloc[:, 1].astype(int)))

#~~> Calculate sum for each delimited list in F3:F6
summed_values = [
    sum(key_value_dict.get(key.strip(), 0) for key in item.split(',')) if item else 0
    for item in delimited_lists
]

#~~> Output the results as a list of lists to spill over multiple cells
[[value] for value in summed_values]

Output as Python Object - Dataframe

Output as Excel Values


So do this:
SUM(SUMIF(A$3:A11,TEXTSPLIT(D3,",",,,1,","),B$3:B11))



++ Excel formula is best suited for this task if the data is not too large...

No access to Python in Excel in the app version of Excel, but it can be done using regular Excel functions using Office 365:
=MAP(F4:F7,LAMBDA(x,SUM(LOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(x,","),I4:J12))))
Or without Lambda: =MMULT(TOROW(J4:J12)*ISNUMBER(FIND(","&TOROW(I4:I12)&",",","&F4:F7&",")),IFERROR(J4:J12^0,0))
